# HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync method not works correctly(Serialization not works correctly)

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have a Web api controller and i used HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync() method; my object(Employee) is inherited from base class(Person) but after the object is posted to the Api, The Object type is changed(unserialized correctly);
Here is my classes:- 
**Before Sending, the Object type is Employee
After Sending,  the Object type is Person**
please see the attachments

```
public class Person
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class CreateEmployeeRequest 
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Before Sending, the Object type is Employee After Sending, the Object type is Person.

Well then, serialization is working perfectly. Your `CreateEmployeeRequest` object contains a `Person` object, not an employee. That's why you see it on the other end.

If you want to be able to deserialize a derived, you'll have to pass the `$type` flag inside your JSON to specify to which derived type it should deserialize to, using the `TypeNameHandling` property of `JsonSerializerSettings`:

```
string jsonTypeNameAll =   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employeeRequest,  Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help; but i want to know how to use your solution;please provide me a sample

Comment: i passed jsonTypeNameAll  to client.PostAsJsonAsync() but it doesn't work

Comment: I am waiting your help

Comment: @Ahmed How did you do that? `PostAsJsonAsync` doesn't accept any serialization settings.

Comment: var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(createEmployeeRequest, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
                });

                var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/OrganizationService", data);

Comment: please, give me sample on how to do this with HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync() method

Comment: Any help for this issue

Comment: Hello,I solved by var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
                {
                    SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
                    }
                };
                
                HttpContent content = new ObjectContent(createEmployeeRequest.GetType(), createEmployeRequest, formatter);